# Need to obtain a 1mV signal

Tags: voltage, 5v, source

I have a 5V power source. For one of my op amps (LM358) I need a 1mV reference voltage as i am comparing it against a sensor input (greater than 1mV). This will allow LM358 to allow my Vcc voltage to flow as an output.

MY problem is how do I drop from 5V to 1mV? I have spent 3 days searching and the only conclusion that was given to me was to use 500M ohms in resistance. I dont feel that is right.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of sensor?

Comment: TSOP 4838. for receiving IR signals

Comment: How did you come up with "1mV" to start with? TSOP 4838 is an open-collector output device with an internal pull-up. You will get output signal of 100mV to VCC.

Comment: Erm, TSOP4838 has a digitial output. It is either <100mV or 5V. Why are you trying to compare to 1mV?

Comment: Barley, Speculation at this point as I have not tested any sensors yet. this is all just theory so far. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have bigger problems than generating 1mV from 5v. You do realise that a LM358 has up to 2mV input voltage offset? I strongly suspect that a design based on a 1mV reference voltage has not been fully thought through.

Anyhow, generating 1mV from 5v doesn't need a silly value resistor, just 2 in a ratio of 4999:1. For instance 1Mohm and 200ohms arranged as a voltage divider will give you approximately 1mV, with the practical tolerance of the resistors dominating the accuracy.

Comment: you are correct int he sense that the idea is still concept and theory. this is why I am asking for any information to aid in this endeavor. But a voltage divider sounds like the path to go and I am not entirely sure on the output voltage of the sensor as of this exact moment. again theory to this point

Comment: 1mV reference goes to the territory of "forget about it". That's 0.2ppm or about 0.02%. You'd need special circuitry with purpose-built tuning to pull that off.

Answer (score 3):

While this not an answer as to how you generate the 1mV signal, it should answer an implied question which is presumable how you interface to the TSOP4838.

[TSOP4838](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2032354.pdf) is an IR receiver which has a **digital** output. It is either <100mV (low) or the supply voltage Vs (high). There is no reason to compare the output to 1mV.

The connections are even shown for you in the application circuit from the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2032354.pdf):

[image: Application Circuit]

Comment: tom, You are correct as i misread the datasheet and realize that now. :)